# executenonquery in c#.net and bind it in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

I'm a beginner in c#.net. I'm having problem in binding the database (mysql) to datagridview. The error shows that my query is wrong. I pretty sure the query was right as I tested it on MySQL script. And I try to show it in datagridview by the way. dbMetName is datagridview. Here is my code

```
private void Binding()
    {
        string connStr = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        try
        {
            string database = schemaForm.getData;
            dtable = new DataTable();
            bindingSource = new BindingSource(); ;

                conn.Open();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Metabolite_Name" +
                                      "FROM " + database +
                                      ".Metabolites WHERE"+
                                      " MetaboliteID IN ('met1', 'met2');";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlData.SelectCommand = command;
                sqlData.Fill(dtable);
                bindingSource.DataSource = dtable;
                dbMetName.DataSource = dtable;
                dtable.Columns.Add("Metabolite Name");
                dbMetName.DataSource = dtable;
                conn.Close();        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Passing value from getData form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DynamicSimulator_v2
{
       public partial class SchemaName : Form
   {
      private static string data;
    public SchemaName()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data=txtDB.Text;
        this.Hide();
    }

    public string getData
    {
        set
        {
            data = txtDB.Text;
        }
        get
        {
          return data;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing space between `Metabolite_Name` and `FROM`:

```
"SELECT Metabolite_Name" +
"FROM " + database +
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns nothing but the number of affected lines. Try this:

```
public DataTable GetDBDataTable(MySqlConnection dbconnection, string table, string columns = "*", string clause = "")
{
    MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT " + columns + " FROM " + table + " " + clause +";", dbconnection);
    MySqlDataAdapter mysqlad = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mysqlad.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}
```